# Dual group endowed with the compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, duality-theorems

I wanted to ask a question.
Let $G^*$ be the dual group of an abelian topological group $G$ ($G^*$ is defined to be the group of all continuous homomorphisms from $G$ to the circle group $T$). I wanted to show that $G^*$ endowed
with the compact-open topology is itself a topological group.
Can someone help me with it?

Thank you

Comment: Does $G$ perhaps have some additional properties, like local compactness? That would help.

Comment: You can have a look here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89651/proof-that-the-pontryagin-dual-of-a-topological-group-is-a-topological-group